# Access QGraphicsItems in a QGraphicsScene in constant time?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to interoperate a `QAbstractTableModel` and `QGraphicsScene`. Its not very fun.

I'm thinking of keeping the data in the table as userData in `QGraphicsItem`. Is there a constant time way to get the `GraphicsItems` in a scene?

For example, this function appears to sort the items?

`QList<QGraphicsItem *> QGraphicsScene::items(Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::DescendingOrder) const`

Comment: How can anything that needs to be done on multiple elements be constant time?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You can get a pointer to the start of a `std::vector` in constant time. For example, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: That's not an operation on multiple elements.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sure. That's not my question. It ends up that the functions I could find that give you access to elements inside a QGraphicsScene appear to perform some sorting operation. Which is undesired. Do you happen to know of a way to access the items in constant time?

Comment: That contradicts the title of your question. Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Okay, now that makes sense!